# Efficiently update columns based on one of the columns split value

Tags: python, dataframe

So here is my code updating many column values based on a condition of split values of the column 'location'. The code works fine, but as its iterating by row it's not efficient enough. Can anyone help me to make this code work faster please?

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print index
    location_split =row['location'].split(':')
    after_county=False
    after_province=False
    for l in location_split:

        if l.strip().endswith('ED'):
            df[index, 'electoral_district'] = l

        elif l.strip().startswith('County'):
            df[index, 'county'] = l
            after_county = True

        elif after_province ==True:
            if l.strip()!='Ireland':
                df[index, 'dublin_postal_district'] = l

        elif after_county==True:
            df[index, 'province'] = l.strip()
            after_province = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'map' was what I needed :)

```
def fill_county(column):
    res = ''
    location_split = column.split(':')

    for l in location_split:
        if l.strip().startswith('County'):
            res= l.strip()
            break
    return res

df['county'] = map(fill_county, df['location'])
```